# How do I do a create table query with Eloquent outside of Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

We're using Eloquent **without Laravel** (long story) for an app we're working on and everything is going fine but we've hit a small snag when trying to dynamically create tables from within the app.

The app is basically a ticket tracking and management system and each upon submission of the user-end form an entry is made in our `tickets` table with a field of `uuid`. This field corresponds to a table with the name of that same uuid (`f46ffeec091c4b9d9f406d65a50ab9e6`, for example). That table in the database that has more complete details and more fields relating to the ticket.

I've tried a LOT of different variations now but anytime I try to run something like

```
Capsule::query("CREATE TABLE `$uuid` LIKE `tickettable`");
```

We get a successful return (well- no errors, at least) but the table doesn't actually get created. We've tried with defined class names instead of `Capsule`, using `Schema`, running it within another class (`ClassName::query(...);`), `$table = new Class(); $table->query(...);`... 
Nothing seems to be working.

Running something like `Schema::create($uuid, function(Blueprint $table){...});` completely fails.

Running `Capsule` seems to be the closest to working but still no dice. Any thoughts?

Comment: Creating *N* tables with arbitrary names really goes against relational database design principles. What's the motivation behind creating an unlimited number of tables?

Comment: Each UUID table has 100+ columns in addition to the 50+ columns in the tickets table. Each of those 100+ columns has the potential to have a LOT of info in it so to keep things loading quickly for end users we came up with the dynamic UUID table solution.

Comment: Not the best solution but this is also running on a fairly archaic VM and large queries have historically crashed the MySQL server (again, long story involving legacy apps)

Comment: It really sounds like MySQL is not a good fit for what you're trying to do if that's your solution. What about Postgres with JSONB columns? What about a document store of some kind? I think whatever MySQL solution you come up with will be wildly over-complicated because of the square peg-round hole problem.

Comment: If you're really stuck with MySQL, MySQL 5.7+ supports JSON as well, though it's not as flexible as Postgres. You could probably get a lot farther by taking a semi-schemaless approach to this depending on your read/write patterns. If this is a huge issue for your business, engaging with a DBA consultant is probably a good call if only to get other ideas.

Comment: I hear you... Structure and principles aside- why would something like `Capsule::query("CREATE TABLE `$uuid` LIKE `tickettable`");` not work? Isn't that kind of the whole point of the `query()` method in Eloquent?

Comment: That should work, so unless you're getting an error it's hard to say what's wrong. What about making a stored procedure to do the same thing?

Comment: Nope- no errors. Returns success but no table created. I'm already out of the office but will try a stored proc on Monday. And thanks for the tips on the alternatives. Hopefully we can move past legacy support some day.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Capsule::schema()->create($uuid, function(Blueprint $table) {
    [...]
});
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?

Comment: Sorry- been away from my computer for a while. That was not working, unfortunately. I ended up doing a really jenky patch because we had to get the app to prod. When I get a chance to play with it more I'll post my solution. Thanks for the suggestion, regardless.